# residuals vs actuals plot

Tags: regression, machine-learning, residuals, nonlinear-regression

Please find the residuals vs actual plot for four of my regression models. I am using Gaussian process regression models on a data set of small size with 5 features and around 50 rows. Hence using leave-one out cross validation. I have plotted the results of all N leave-one CV models. I see that the residuals vs actuals plot follow a linear pattern (at least with models a,b and d). For the lower values of the actual, residuals are positive and for higher values of the actual, the residues are negative. Is this a common pattern?

Do you have any suggestions to improve the regression? I was thinking of improving the regression by a two-stage regression by adding a compensation factor based on my first regression? Is it valid? I am an academic and planning to publish the results of my regression.

Many thanks for your time and attention[image]

Comment: Scales are different in a-c, b and d, could you provide more information about the model for each of the images?

Comment: As a matter of fact, the thing about this "linear relationship" comes from the fact that your predictions are worse when you go far from the mean/median of "actual".
So, it's a way to know that your model is not fitting well (errors should follow a normal distribution around 0).

The thing is, if there's any feature that has not been used on your model, you can use it to plot your residuals (and the relationship). If there's correlation, perhaps you should include this feature in your model (because that variable affects the target)

Comment: Hi Dave, These are the outputs for 4 different regression problems. I am predicting a different output variable in each case. Thats why the scale is different for each image

Comment: Or even the same variables used (because the relationship of a variable with the predictor may be NOT LINEAR).
In addition, have you included interaction effects on your model(y~Intercept+x1+x2+x1:x2...)? Or just additive (y~Intercept+x1+x2...)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs.  I will check if I can add more features to improve the results and update you. I have a related quick question. I have an understanding that any model will underpredict for a higher values of actual and overpredict for lower values. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi Dave, I am using Gaussian process regression with a squared exponential kernel. So, I am assuming that the model will include the interaction terms.

Comment: That's often correct, Ed.  It's one reason we rarely examine plots of residuals vs. actuals, but instead use plots of residuals vs. *predicted* values.

Comment: Appreciate your helpful reply, Whuber. Many thanks

Comment: @Dave, Your answer is very helpful. But I am unable to accept it or upvote it as your reply is in the form of a comment. If you can post the reply as an answer, I would like to upvote it. Apologies,if I missed something. I am a new user